# Why pca.transform has different results from calculation from scratch?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I have been doing PCA with scikit-learn.
However, I just got to know that the following two approaches giveve different results:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=0.95)

X_proj = pca.fit_transform(X) # << THIS AND

np.dot(X, pca.components_.T)  # << THIS GIVE DIFFERENT RESULTS
```

Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post a [mre] with some actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The sklearn PCA module has **normalized** the input data.

We take MNIST dataset as example.

Load the module and dataset.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
```

Load the first data

```
X = digits.data[0].reshape(8,8)
plt.imshow(X)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Use PCA.

```
print(pca.fit_transform(X))
X -= np.mean(X, axis=0) # normalize
print(np.dot(X, pca.components_.T))
```

Two output would be the same.

```
[[12.35977044 -4.83699252 -0.46662515]
 [ 5.86229378 10.53312359 -3.75283451]
 [-8.32285024  1.25214592 -1.06726234]
 [-8.14946302 -3.13767167 -0.24623081]
 [-7.7867473  -4.40094175 -1.06614822]
 [-8.41834525 -0.27216078  0.35837631]
 [ 1.49545914  5.65672511  6.04353692]
 [12.95988243 -4.79422791  0.1971878 ]]
[[12.35977044 -4.83699252 -0.46662515]
 [ 5.86229378 10.53312359 -3.75283451]
 [-8.32285024  1.25214592 -1.06726234]
 [-8.14946302 -3.13767167 -0.24623081]
 [-7.7867473  -4.40094175 -1.06614822]
 [-8.41834525 -0.27216078  0.35837631]
 [ 1.49545914  5.65672511  6.04353692]
 [12.95988243 -4.79422791  0.1971878 ]]
```